# Using v-model to get the result of a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build out a table that has a lot of moving parts and columns calculating off one another. In the below example I am trying to have `working_capital` for each repeater item be a calculation of `(current_assets - current_liabilities)`. I can't use `computed` here because the calculation needs to be able to accept a parameter of the object that is being passed. Later on (not displayed in this code) I need to use the value of `working_capital` in a percentage calculation based of other object properties (not displayed in this code) but the answer to this will be able to solve that down the road. Here is the current setup. (Note: I trimed out the table / HTML and a lot of the component code to make this easier to read/answer).

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="financial-row" v-for="financial in yearlyFinancials">
            <input type="number" v-model="financial.current_assets" />
            <input type="number" v-model="financial.current_liabilities" />
            <input type="number" v-model="workingCapital(financial)" /> <!-- This line doesn't work / Somehow needs to be calculated AND modeled to use this value later -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function(){
      return {
          yearlyFinancials: [
              {
                  year: 2017,
                  current_assets: 340,
                  current_liabilities: 176,
                  working_capital: 0 // This needs to a calculated 
              },
              {
                  year: 2016,
                  current_assets: 360,
                  current_liabilities: 200,
                  working_capital: 0 // This needs to a calculated 
              }
          ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
        workingCapital: function(obj){
            return (obj.current_assets - obj.current_liabilities);
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Again, the result I am trying to achieve here is having the `working_capital` property of each `yearlyFinancials` objects be always calculated AND modeled because I will be using the value of each `working_capital` for another set of calculations later down the road.

Any points in the right direction will be a huge help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property which calculates the `workingCapital`

```
calculatedyearlyFinancials() {
  return this.yearlyFinancials.map(item => {
    item.workingCapital = item.current_assets - item.current_liabilities
    return item
  })
}
```

And in your template:

```
    <div class="financial-row" v-for="financial of calculatedyearlyFinancials"> <!-- USE :key here -->
        <input type="number" v-model="financial.current_assets" />
        <input type="number" v-model="financial.current_liabilities" />
        <input type="number" v-model="financial.workingCapital" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Your a freakin life saver. This is working 100% how i wanted it.